# Temporarily assigning roles using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to write the moderation function of my discord bot and I want to implement Tempmute. There is nothing in the documentation that I can find that lists any ways to temporarily assign roles or assign those permissions to mute a specific person.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: @Skully Didnt really mean to ask people to code for me, I was just asking if anyone could find a place in the documentation that I had missed or some other docs where it mentions these kinds of solutions. Sorry for any misconceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack! Try this to remove it after a set time:

```py
await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
await member.remove_roles(role)
```